# SIP 200OK for UPDATE arrives after 180 Ringing

Tags: sip, sip-server

When testing SIP calls on the SIP server that we are developing i came across a case where the 200Ok response for UPDATE message arrives after 180 ringing is received on the SIP server.
In other words the device at **B sends 180 Ringing to the server before sending the 200OK response for UPDATE**.
The call flow is per the attached image -
[Late 200OK response image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f043R.jpg)
The question is- Is this correct with respect to call flow. Does the standard allow this. Is the device B at fault?

I tried to get answer from web and RFCs but unable to get correct information. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to handle this situation?

Comment: This is off topic here, as it's not a programming question.

Comment: Not a programming question. I recommend you to add more details for the SIP stack you are using or contacting the correct email alias. (Asterisk Freeswitch, Kamailio, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

It's valid from the standard. And there is no reason it should break anything in your app. 200 Ok for UPDATE has one meaning: the UPDATE was correctly received/handled on remote side. No matter *when* you receive it!

As a sidenote, User B should not send 183 and later a 180: provisionnal response status code sent by one *same* User-Agent should always increase. That doesn't look to be your question, but worth to be pointed out!